# How to verify information in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, unit-testing, webdriver

So i created USER using API and now i want to verify that that user got also created in DB, Im using MySQL for it. WebdriverIO, axios, pool.query. Is any ideas how to do expect."some value in DB".to.be.equal('name')

Comment: You can do a `SELECT` query to check that the row in the database was created.

Comment: But if the `INSERT` query didn't get an error, you can be confident that the user was created.

Comment: yeh, but how to automate it with chai for example? like i can create pool.query(select * from *) and then how to verify that i have this row? just do something like expect(results.table.last_name).tobeequal('williams')???

Comment: If your question is about unit testing, you should add that tag.